# Changing dynamically the color of an Awesome Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf, font-awesome

I want to change the colour of an Awesome Icon, and I created this piece of code, but instead of giving me the colour, I got an 'undefined'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeAIColor(idName) {
    alert ($('idAwesomeIcon').css("color"));
}
</script>

<a href="#" th:onclick="'changeIconColor();'">
    <span th:if="${#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
        <i id="idAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg"   style="color:#009900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <span th:if="${!#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
        <i d="idAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: since they are inside a conditional tag if, the ID is unique

Comment: You have some HTML error. Like this `<i d="idAwesomeIcon"` Are you trying to change the color? Or display it on the alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the `id` selector `#` in your JQuery. Also use `idName` of the `changeAIColor` function in your selector. So, the query becomes `($('#'+idName).css("color")`. Please note that you have used same `id` as `idAwesomeIcon` multiple times. `id` values should be used uniquely in HTML page.

```js
function changeAIColor(idName) {
  alert ($('#'+idName).css("color"));
}

changeAIColor('idAwesomeIcon');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" th:onclick="'changeIconColor();'"> 
  <span th:if="${#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
      <i id="idAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg"   style="color:#009900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
 <span th:if="${!#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
      <i id="idAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `$('#idAwesomeIcon').css("color")`

Also `<i d="idAwesomeIcon"` isn't right. The ID should be different and should actually be `id=""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.AwesomeIcon').each(function(){
      alert ($(this).css("color"));
    });
</script>

<a href="#" th:onclick="'changeIconColor();'">
    <span th:if="${#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg AwesomeIcon"   style="color:#009900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <span th:if="${!#lists.contains(userMenus, menu)}">
        <i  class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg AwesomeIcon"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</a>
```

Change your ID to class and change your JS accordingly.